# How can I debug a conditional based on isinstance?

Tags: python, types

I have written the function below.  It will work if I pass it an integer or string:  If I pass an integer, the program will calculate the factorial, and if I pass a string, it will check the type with `isinstance` and will print the error message.

But, if I pass a float number or a negative number, the program will print an error... in my *second* condition.  I have said that if `n` is less than 0, then print that error message, but apparently it won't work, and I don't know why.

```
def factorial(n):
 if not isinstance(n,int):
  print('Factorial is only defined for integers.')
  return(None)
 elif n<0:
  print('Factorial is not defined for negative integers.')
  return(None)
 elif n==0:
  return(1)
 else:
  return(n*factorial(n-1))
```

How can I change the program so that my conditionals work for float and negative numbers?  I don't want to use `try` and `except`.

Comment: Can you show us how you call this method with a float? The method itself looks good.

Comment: `if not isinstance(n,int) or isinstance(n, float):`

Comment: Well when i put  a float the program will give this error : TypeError : unsupported operand type(s) for + : 'int' and 'str'

Comment: `Also i don't want to use try and except.` - you shouldn't be using those, but `raise` is absolutely appropriate here. Don't just `return None`.

Comment: The code is working fine for me in all the cases, the problem must be in the caller. Can you add it to the post?

Comment: Thank you guys :)  i used what rsm said and it is working now ! What was the problem ?

Comment: I agree with k4ppa --- I can't reproduce your problem at all.  In both Python 2 and 3, this function correctly rejected floats like `5.5` and even `5.0` with the `isinstance` test.  I believe your problem is elsewhere... meaning rsm's solution might be _hiding_ your real problem, not solving it.